# Authentication issue when sending emails with Gmail API in Django using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gmail

```
class SendEmailView(APIView):
    serializer_class=SendEmailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if not user.gmail_credentials:
            return Response({"error": "Gmail not linked"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(json.loads(user.gmail_credentials))
        if creds.expired:
            creds.refresh(Request())

        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        to_email = request.data.get("to")
        subject = request.data.get("subject")
        message_text = request.data.get("message")

        if not all([to_email, subject, message_text]):
            return Response({"error": "Missing fields"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            message = MIMEText(message_text)
            message['to'] = to_email
            message['from'] = user.email  # Replace with your sender address
            message['subject'] = subject

            raw_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
            message_body = {'raw': raw_message}

            sent_message = service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message_body).execute()
            return Response({"message_id": sent_message['id']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.GetMessage",
          "service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to send the email through Django, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.